# cProfile seems to override the normal value of `__file__`, how adapt?

Tags: python, path, cprofile

I have a program that relies on the `__file__` built-in global to provide the path to data associated with the program, as in `path_to_stuff = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'stuff')`. The problem is that when I run this with `python -m cProfile myprog`, the value of `__file__` is no longer the path to `myprog` but rather (apparently) the path to the cProfile module, where my stuff definitely isn't.

I've read [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html?highlight=cprofile#cProfile) and searched here and don't see anything about this. Is there a way to either (a) get cProfile to leave `__file__` alone or (b) know at runtime that I'm running under cProfile so I could initialize the path with a literal string in this special case?

Edit: or, I guess, (c), is there a better way to find a dir that will always be right next to the program.py?

Comment: Maybe I should add Mac OS X 10.6 (snow leopard) python 2.6 as distributed with the system.

Answer (score 0):

(b) seems easy to do. In your program.py, check the value of `__name__` . If you are running the program directly the value of `__name__` would be `"__main__"`. Instead, the value will be different if you are running it under cProfile.

**Edit**: I am unable to replicate your problem. cProfile doesnot seem to change either the `__name__` or the `__file__` value when I try it. You can also try running the profiler with in you script by calling `cProfile.run()`

Comment: `[21:35 ~/Dropbox/David/PPQT/scratch] cat printfile.py`
`print __file__`
`[21:35 ~/Dropbox/David/PPQT/scratch] python printfile.py`
`printfile.py`
`[21:35 ~/Dropbox/David/PPQT/scratch] python -m cProfile printfile.py`
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py` `4 function calls in 0.000 CPU seconds
(etc)`

Comment: Make a one-line prog printname.py `print __name__` and  run it both with python and python -m cProfile and the output is the same  both times. Unlike the output of `print __file__`

Comment: It is strange that the outputs are different for `__name__` and `__file__`. I ran it on Ubuntu Natty and there were no problems.

Comment: thanks for trying but I went into my Ubuntu VM (10.04 LTS) and ran my test of `print __file__` Executing `python profiletest.py` it prints `profiletest.py` but executing with `python -m cProfile profiletest.py` it prints `/usr/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py` This is exactly the same problem as in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for you if you still have the problem.

```
path_to_stuff = os.path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(sys.argv[0])), 'stuff')
```